# How do I see if there are multiple rows with an identical value in particular column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for an efficient way to exclude rows from my `SELECT` statement `WHERE` more than one row is returned with an identical value for a certain column.

Specifically, I am selecting a bunch of accounts, but need to exclude accounts where more than one is found with the same SSN associated.

Comment: Do you want to exclude _all_ records that meet that criteria or do you want to exclude only duplicates, i.e. show _one_ record per SSN?

Comment: I want to exclude **all** records that meet the criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your detailed suggestions.  When it was all said and done, I needed to use a **correlated subquery**.  Essentially, this is what I had to do:

```
SELECT acn, ssn, [date] FROM Account a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Account WHERE ssn = a.ssn AND [date] < a.[date])
```

Hope this helps someone.

---

I never updated this...  **In my final submission, I achieved this through a left join to increase efficiency** (the correlated subquery was not acceptable as it took a significant amount of time to run, checking each record against over 150K others).

Here is what had to be done to solve my problem:

```
SELECT acn, ssn 
  FROM Account a
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT ssn, COUNT(1) AS counter FROM Account
    GROUP BY ssn) AS counters 
    ON a.ssn = counters.ssn
  WHERE counter IS NULL OR counter = 0
```

Answer (score 12):

this will return all SSNs with exactly 1 row

```
select ssn,count(*)
from SomeTable
group by ssn
having count(*) = 1
```

this will return all SSNs with more than 1 row

```
select ssn,count(*)
from SomeTable
group by ssn
having count(*) > 1
```

Your full query would be like this (will work on SQL Server 7 and up)

```
select a.* from account a
join(
select ssn
from SomeTable
group by ssn
having count(*) = 1) s on a.ssn = s.ssn
```

Comment: the second query equals the first ;)

Comment: `having count(*) > 1` in second query

Comment: Yes..victim of CTRL + C, CTRL + V and then not changing the = sign, tx

Comment: This will return SSN's, not accounts.

Comment: I don't have the full DDL, I added another query that will show him how to do it

Answer (score 6):

For SQL 2005 or above you can try this:

```
WITH qry AS
(
    SELECT a.*,
        COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ssn) dup_count
      FROM accounts a
)
SELECT *
  FROM qry
 WHERE dup_count = 1
```

For SQL 2000 and 7:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM accounts a INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT ssn
          FROM accounts b
            GROUP BY ssn 
            HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
    )  b ON a.ssn = b.ssn
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM #Temp
WHERE SSN NOT IN (SELECT ssn FROM #Temp GROUP BY ssn HAVING COUNT(ssn) > 1)
```